# cycle structure of bounded genus graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given fixed genus $k$ is there some $q=f(k)$ for which for any graph $G$ of bounded genus $k$  there are $q$ planar subgraphs $G_1,G_2,..,G_q$ of $G$ 
 such that each cycle of $G$ can be written as the symmetric difference of cycles in $G_i$?
If true what is a bound of  $f(k)$  can you use a fixed (non-planar) embedding of $G$ such that each $G_i$ is planar?
If not is there a condition that can be relaxed?

Comment: Are these $q$ sets supposed to cover $V$?

Comment: Okay maybe for simplicity assume that every vertex of $G$ is in some cycle so you end up covering $G$